# How can I order HDD with my data via mail?

Tags: backup

I have really crappy internet connection and need to find a way to get my data that is remotely on my VPS.

If there is any way(or service) that can write my data on any HDD and send it to me?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a VPS, you'll need to contact their support team to make the request. They may request that you send in a drive or they may simply charge you for a drive they provide. Either way they will likely charge a fairly large amount to copy the data for you. Data backup copies often charge more than $150 for the service. Either way, it's your VPS provider that will dictate the terms.

If you don't want to pay for the service, you should compress the data on the server first before downloading it. You may also see if you can find someone near you that has access to a faster connection to download the data on that connection to a USB hard drive for you.